# Irreducible Polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p (T) [x]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, divisibility, irreducible-polynomials

Let p be prime, and $K = {\bf F}_p (T)$ an extension of ${\bf F}_p$. How can i prove that the polynomial $x^p - T$ is irreducible in $K[x]$

Comment: Needs correction

Comment: Corrected now, thank you.

Comment: Algebraic or transcendental extension K

Comment: Should it matter? My question is out of an example my teacher wrote, he just said the polynomial was irreducible in K, but he didnt proove the result nor specified if it was algebraic or trascendental.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Since $F_p(T) = \operatorname{Quot}(F_p[T])$ and $x^p -T$ is a monic polynomial you may use Gauss‘ lemma to reduce to showing that $x^p-T$ is irreducible in $F_p[T][x]$, where it follows from Eisensteins criterion, because $T$ is prime.

Comment: This is the argument! I need to vote to close the question as a duplicate. Relatively experienced users can guess that this has been asked earlier. Don't worry too much, the upvote is mine.

Comment: That’s fine. Since I am on mobile I am not good in finding links for duplicates and since the argument is short I thought Id simply restate it.